# Calculate business days by iterating over columns

Tags: pandas, numpy, date

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

[image]

I would like to calculate the number of business days between the event date and the month/days show in the columns. The output would look like the below with the NaTs converted to nans:

[image]

Does anyone know how might be best to go about achieving this using pandas?

Comment: please provide your input in a reproducible format, not an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dates are already of datetime type*, use [`numpy.busday_count`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) and broadcasting/masking:

```
import numpy as np

tmp = df.filter(regex=r'\d{4}-\d{2}')
df[tmp.columns] = np.where(tmp.notna(),
                           np.busday_count(df['Event_Date'].to_numpy(dtype='datetime64[D]')[:,None],
                                           tmp.fillna('0').to_numpy(dtype='datetime64[D]')),
                           np.nan)
```

* else convert with `cols = df.drop(columns='Account').columns ; df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)`.

Output:

```
  Account Event_Date  2023-01  2023-02  2023-03  2023-04  2023-05  2023-06  2023-07
0       A 2023-04-25    -77.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1       B 2023-06-02      NaN      NaN      NaN     21.0     51.0      NaN      NaN
2       C 2023-04-25      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      7.0      NaN      NaN
```

Used input:

```
from pandas import Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame({'Account': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'Event_Date': [Timestamp('2023-04-25 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-06-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-04-25 00:00:00')],
                   '2023-01': [Timestamp('2023-01-06 00:00:00'), NaT, NaT],
                   '2023-02': [NaT, NaT, NaT],
                   '2023-03': [NaT, NaT, NaT],
                   '2023-04': [NaT, Timestamp('2023-07-01 00:00:00'), NaT],
                   '2023-05': [NaT, Timestamp('2023-08-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-05-04 00:00:00')],
                   '2023-06': [NaT, NaT, NaT],
                   '2023-07': [NaT, NaT, NaT]})
```